# How do you show a tooltip in XAML only when the mouse pointer is directly over the element

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've got a `Grid` and within the grid I have child elements. The grid has a `ToolTip` which I only want to show when the Mouse pointer is directly over the `Grid` (and not over any of the child elements).

I've written a little XAML sample below to show the problem. It contains a `Grid` (with 2 columns, 2 rows and a `ToolTip`), and a `Button` in the Top Left grid cell.

When I move the mouse pointer over the `Button` it shows the `ToolTip`. And when I move the mouse pointer over the `Grid` it also shows the `ToolTip`. I only want the `ToolTip` to be displayed when the mouse is directly over the `Grid` (and not over the `Button`).

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        Height="350" 
        Width="525">

    <Grid ToolTip="I'm over the grid"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          Background="LightSteelBlue">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Content="MY BUTTON"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

There is a [IsMouseDirectlyOver property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.iinputelement.ismousedirectlyover%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so I was wonder if there is any way I could use that to only show the `ToolTip` when the mouse is directly over the `Grid`.

Comment: Then why not set tool tip against button? Also if you would remove `Background` from the `Grid` only `Button` would be hit test visible

Comment: Move the Background assignment to the Window.

Comment: I only want the ToolTip to be displayed when the mouse is over the Grid. (And no ToolTip displayed when its over the button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just detach that parent relationship and move it to an element that falls behind the other objects but as a child will still receive the MouseOver just for the grid and none of the other elements, one way would be like;

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        Height="350" 
        Width="525">

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          Background="LightSteelBlue">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

       <Rectangle Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                  Fill="Transparent"
                  ToolTip="I'm only shown when I have a mouse on me instead of all the children, because I'm special :)"/>

        <Button Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Content="MY BUTTON"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Hope this helps, cheers.